# Why does it add spacing inside a table cell?

Tags: html

Why does it add a space to the right side inside the first cell? How can I remove it? I included an image of the results. It's supposed to be the american flag, but I just cant get the space in the first cell to go away. I'm new to coding I just need to make an american flag out of a table as a class project.

[image: table image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Flag2</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    table,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table width="300px;">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>*</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're best to show what you have tried. Add your code here and maybe someone will help.

Comment: can you use a space.?

Comment: @J. Martinez, We are here to help you, if you stuck with your code, not to do your homework.

Comment: + Always post an example of your code. So we can debug it. (And like said before: we are here to help and not to write code for you).

Answer (score 0):

You want to collapse the border

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```